# Get only best ranked rows from a subquery

Tags: sql, plsql, rank

I want to get the price of an article for a specific customer.
There are several levels of prices which i ranked in my query.
So Article A has a price on rank 1, 4, 6. The result should always be the lowest ranked price.

```
Article B rank 3 ,5
```

So article A price is ranked 1 and Article b is price ranked 3.
My query is below .

```
SELECT p2.* FROM(
SElect ART_ID, MIN(RANG) RANG FROM (
Select p.ART_ID, p.betrag ,
CASE p.PREIS_EBENE WHEN 'KA' THEN 1 WHEN 'KW' THEN 2 WHEN 'W' THEN 7 WHEN 'A' THEN 6 ELSE 99 END RANG
FROM MDART a
INNER JOIN MDPRSVK p ON (a.KLIENT_ID = p.KLIENT_ID AND a.ART_ID = p.ART_ID)
WHERE ICP_KZ.IS_SET(KENNUNG_USER, 'P') = 1
ORDER BY RANG)
GROUP BY ART_ID) T

INNER JOIN MDPRSVK p2 ON (p2.ART_ID = T.ART_ID AND p2.PREIS_EBENE = p.PREIS_EBENE)
```

i want to have every article appearing only once in the result

Comment: It looks like your `T` subquery already does what you want. Why are you joining MDPRSVK again? Please show example data and expected output.

Comment: i get two rows because i also need the "BETRAG" (is german for amount) so if i want the betrag i need to put it into the group by and i get two rows:   32A00000426 840 6
32A00000426 841 1

Comment: Why have you tagged your request PL/SQL? This is Oracle's programming language, whereas you are looking for a SQL query. Are you using Oracle? Or another DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your request PL/SQL, so I guess your DBMS may be Oracle.

If I understand correctly, the table MDPRSVK contains several prices per ART_ID. And you want to select each ART_ID's best price (best to worst: 'KA' -> 'KW' -> 'A' -> 'W' -> any other PREIS_EBENE).

You can use a window function (`ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`) for this:

```
select *
from mdprsvk
order by row_number() 
         over (partition by art_id 
               order by decode(preis_ebene, 'KA', 1, 'KW', 2, 'A', 3, 'W', 4, 5))
fetch first row with ties;
```

This is standard SQL. In Oracle, `FETCH FIRST` is available as of version 12c. In earlier versions you'd use a subquery instead:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    mdprsvk.*,
    row_number() over (partition by art_id 
                       order by decode(preis_ebene, 'KA', 1, 'KW', 2, 'A', 3, 'W', 4, 5))
      as rn
  from mdprsvk
)
where rn = 1;
```

Or use Oracle`s`KEEP FIRST`:

```
select art_id, max(betrag)
               keep (dense_rank first
                     order by decode(preis_ebene, 'KA', 1, 'KW', 2, 'A', 3, 'W', 4, 5))
from mdprsvk
group by art_id;
```

It is not clear, how MDART comes into play. It looks like you want to restrict your results to articles for certain clients and KENNUNG_USER is the column in MDART to check. If so, add a `WHERE` clause:

```
where exists
(
  select *
  from mdart
  where mdart.klient_id = mdprsvk.klient_id
    and mdart.art_id = mdprsvk.art_id
    and icp_kz.is_set(mdart.kennung_user, 'p') = 1
)
```

Or with `IN` instead of `EXISTS`:

```
where (klient_id, art_id) in
(
  select klient_id, art_id
  from mdart
  where icp_kz.is_set(kennung_user, 'p') = 1
)
```

Comment: thank you a lot. the first query is exactly what i needed.